# Get default configuration file for Cisco and Juniper routers

Tags: router, juniper

I am trying to learn the tool Firewall Auditor. For that I need few default configuration files for some routers, like Cisco ASA, PIX 500, 7200, 7600 and Juniper Netscreen 5200, 5600.I tried googling around for such config files, but I was not able to find one.

Can someone suggest me some url where such config files are easily available for download. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I'm also looking for the same thing, and may be for the same reason. I think, it is not possible to get the configuration files of such devices, as those devices are used in high level security purpose.

There is only two ways you can get those configuration files. First is, You have to own them, practically which is very hard and expensive like hell. Second is, you have to work as a Network Admin in a company where these devices are being used.

You can decide which option suits you. I have the second option. Still trying to acquire the files.